# What is Oracle equivalent of mysql_affected_rows?

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, variables, rows-affected

In Mysql, If we insert,delete or update data then by using `mysql_affected_rows(),`
we will get No. of rows affected & same we can use in `PHP` to store it in a `variable`.

So What is Oracle equivalent of mysql_affected_rows?

**How can we get No. of rows affected in Oracle?**

What's the `function name` for the oracle db for the same, so that we can use the same in `PHP` or we can store that value in `PHP variable`?

Comment: which wrapper for interacting with oracle from PHP do you use? OCI?

Comment: You know that MySQL is a part of Oracle? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As google told me :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-num-rows.php

`oci_num_rows()` should do the trick.